# How to pass custom arguments to the xelatex command to Overleaf Community edition?

Tags: xetex, overleaf

I'm writing my diploma thesis and after I added some figures with TikZ, the compilation time is taking 1-2 minutes. I am running the official docker image of Overleaf community Edition on a local server. I have heard that the `XeLatex` spends a lot of time on compression for the output pdf and since bandwidth isn't a problem for me I'm searching for a way to pass custom arguments to the `xetalex` command to reduce the compilation time. Any suggestions given are really appreciated. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I assume it's the same as the hosted overleaf and you can add a latexmkrc file to your project that can specify any commandline that you want

Comment: Yes, I experimented with latexmkrc but I had problem because my project is split in multiple files and I use `\input` command to include them.

Comment: why is that a issue? the `\input` structure makes no difference to the commandline used on the main file